# How change menu in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, less

[image: Example]
I try change `text-transform:none;` to `text-transform:uppercase;` in horisontal menu theme LUMA.
I try add to _theme.less:

```
@navigation-level0-item__text-decoration: uppercase;
@navigation-desktop-level0-item__text-decoration: uppercase;
```

But no changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
@navigation-level0-item__text-transform
```

Doesn't affect desktop navigation and there is no variable to define text-transform.

You have to extend _navigation.less

Create or edit web/css/source/_extend.less in your theme folder and add:

```
@import '_navigation_extend.less';
```

Create web/css/source/_navigation_extend.less:

```
.navigation .level0  > .level-top {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```